# Can you register an ActiveX dll in Java programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, activex

I have a third-party ActiveX dll, and I'd like to register it programmatically at run time, if possible. Can this be done in Java? The application I'm working with is an Eclipse application on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute **regsvr32** via the [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class.

Comment: I ended up registering the dll in the installation script at the time, but if I still wanted to do it programmatically, I think this is what I would need to do.